# Problems with static IP config via interfaces file

Tags: networking, network-manager, static-ip

I'd like to setup a static IP on Kubuntu 17.10 for my desktop PC.

```
ifconfig
enp10s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.100.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
    inet6 fe80::71e0:527e:96cd:4128  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 70:85:c2:41:08:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 12849  bytes 4063036 (4.0 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 10032  bytes 1116381 (1.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
    RX packets 854  bytes 69858 (69.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 854  bytes 69858 (69.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Working interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Not working interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp10s0
iface enp10s0 inet static
address 192.168.100.99
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.100.1
```

After a **sudo service network-manager restart** my connection isn't connected. If I delete the enp10s0 entry (revert back to the working interfaces) and restart the network-manager, the network/internet is working again.

It's a fairly standard setup and not my first time changing something in the interfaces but I can't see my mistake here. Anybody?

Comment: Maybe only a dns problem, try adding `dns-nameservers 192.168.100.1` to `/etc/network/interface`

Comment: I tried it with and without the dns-nameservers entry but no change there.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is using the [Netplan](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan) configuration abstraction from version 17.10.

So instead of `/etc/network/interfaces` we now use `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`

The config for my single interface with static IP:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  #renderer: NetworkManager
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp10s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.100.99/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

`sudo netplan generate` generates the configuration for the network render.

Note: I tried `sudo netplan --debug generate` and kept on running into a message:

> DEBUG: NetworkManager: definition enp10s0 is not for us (backend 1)

But still, a restart assigned the correct IP and everything seems to be working smoothly.

Comment: I got this message when I used a wrong gateway address, in example 192.168.11.1 instead of 192.168.11.2. To figure that out, I had to debug using ```nmcli dev show > /tmp/nmcli.out``` for both before and after applying the netplan using ```sudo netplan --debug apply```